# Python - beginner level - password manager GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been learning Python for 1.5 months now. I am learning in my free time between jobs and other life commitments so my progress may be slow or it may take time for me to reply but I am interested in anyone's opinion and review about my code in order to get better, faster, and get some focus about the mistakes I sometimes make.

In your code review please try to include these aspects:

- code readability
- code efficiency
- any ideas to improve the code or any thoughts you may have

My first project, [PasswordManager](https://github.com/SeanR11/PasswordManager): a GUI tkinter program that gives you the ability to save all passwords you may have in different website on your computer so you don't have to remember those passwords.

**main.py**

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror, showinfo,askyesno
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview, Style
from tkinter import *
from datetime import date
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from io import StringIO

import Cipher
import pandas as pd
import random
import math



class Tk(Tk):
    def destroy(self):
        if data_file is not None:
            csvString = data_file.to_csv(index=False)
            with open(f'{RESOURCE_PATH}/data_file.enc',mode='wb') as save_file:
                save_file.write(Cipher.encrypt(PASSWORD,csvString))
        tkinter.Tk.destroy(self)


def clear_frame(frame_name):
    for widgets in frame_name.winfo_children():
        widgets.destroy()

def motion(event):
    if event.char == 'a':
        print(f"X: {event.x}, Y: {event.y}")

def change_password():
    global PASSWORD
    while True:
        old_pass = askstring('OLD','Type current password',show='•')
        if old_pass == PASSWORD:
            new_pass = askstring('NEW','Type new password',show='•')
            PASSWORD = new_pass
            return True
        else:
            showinfo('NOT MATCH','Current password inserted does not\nmatch current password')
        if old_pass == None:
            return False

def admin_verify():
    global PASSWORD,data_file
    while True:
        inserted_password = askstring('Admin verify', 'Enter admin password\ndecrypt will take 5 seconds',show='•')
        new_file = open(f'{RESOURCE_PATH}/data_file.enc',mode='rb').read()
        if inserted_password is not None:
            try:
                decrypted_file = Cipher.decrypt(inserted_password, new_file).decode()
                csvFormat = StringIO(decrypted_file)
                data_file = pd.read_csv(csvFormat)
                PASSWORD = inserted_password
                showinfo('Success', 'Admin successfully verified')

                return True
            except Cipher.DecryptionException:
               showerror('Failure', 'Wrong password')
        else:
            window.destroy()
            return False



def add_page():

    def add_data():
        website_data = website.get()
        password_data = password.get()
        username_data = username.get()

        verified = askyesno('Verify info',f'Please verify this data\n'
                                        f'website: {website_data}\n'
                                        f'username: {username_data}\n'
                                        f'password: {password_data}')
        if verified:
            global data_file
            if website_data != "" and username_data != "" and password_data != "":
                data = pd.DataFrame({'website': [website_data],
                                     'username': [username_data],
                                     'password': [CRYPTO.encrypt(password_data.encode()).decode()],
                                     'last update': [date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")]})
                data.index = [len(data_file)]
                data_file = pd.concat([data_file, data], ignore_index=False)
                #data_file.to_csv(path_or_buf=f"{RESOURCE_PATH}/passwordmanager.csv", mode="w", header=True, index=False)
                website.delete(0, END)
                username.delete(0, END)
                password.delete(0, END)
                error_label.config(text="Successfully added", fg="green", padx=20)
            else:
                error_label.config(text="Values cant be empty", fg="red", padx=0)

    def generate_password():
        password_generated = []
        chars = [*'abcdefghijklmnopqrstvuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTVUWXYZ!@#$%1234567890']
        for n in range(0, 24):
            password_generated.append(random.choice(chars))
        password.insert(0, "".join(password_generated))

    clear_frame(window)

    small_logo = Canvas(width=200, height=189, highlightthickness=0)
    small_logo.create_image(100, 100, image=LOGO_IMAGE)
    small_logo.pack(pady=20)

    main_frame = Frame(window, borderwidth=10)
    main_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, pad=35)
    main_frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1, pad=35)
    main_frame.rowconfigure(2, weight=1, pad=30)
    main_frame.pack()

    error_label = Label(text="", font=("ariel", 15))
    error_label.place(x=260, y=210)

    website_label = Label(main_frame, text="Website:")
    website_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

    website = Entry(main_frame, width=40)
    website.grid(column=1, row=0)

    username_label = Label(main_frame, text="Email/Username:")
    username_label.grid(column=0, row=1)

    username = Entry(main_frame, width=40)
    username.grid(column=1, row=1)

    password_label = Label(main_frame, text="Password:")
    password_label.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=30)

    password = Entry(main_frame, width=30)
    password.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)

    generate_password_button = Button(main_frame, text="Generate", borderwidth=0, fg=MAIN_WHITE, bg=MAIN_COLOR,
                                      activeforeground=MAIN_COLOR, activebackground=MAIN_WHITE, command=generate_password)
    generate_password_button.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)

    add_button = Button(main_frame, text="ADD", width=50, borderwidth=0,
                        fg=MAIN_WHITE, bg=MAIN_COLOR, activeforeground=MAIN_COLOR, activebackground=MAIN_WHITE,
                        command=add_data)
    add_button.grid(columnspan=2, rowspan=3, pady=20, sticky=E)

    return_button = Button(image=RETURN_IMAGE, borderwidth=0, command=main_page)
    return_button.place(x=10, y=10)

    window.mainloop()


def display_page():
    def last_page(rows):
        if rows[0] != 0:
            rows[0] -= ROWS_PER_PAGE
            rows[1] -= ROWS_PER_PAGE
            data_table.delete(*data_table.get_children())
            for n, data in enumerate(data_file.iloc[rows[0]:rows[1]].iterrows()):
                data = data[1]
                data_table.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=n,
                                  values=(data['website'], data['username'], CRYPTO.decrypt(data['password'].encode()).decode(), data['last update']))
            if len(data_file) != 0:
                indicator.config(text=f"{round(rows[0]/ROWS_PER_PAGE)+1} / {math.ceil(len(data_file)/ROWS_PER_PAGE)}")

    def next_page(rows):
        if rows[1] < len(data_file):
            rows[0] += ROWS_PER_PAGE
            rows[1] += ROWS_PER_PAGE
            data_table.delete(*data_table.get_children())
            for n, data in enumerate(data_file.iloc[rows[0]:rows[1]].iterrows()):
                data = data[1]
                data_table.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=n,
                                  values=(data['website'], data['username'], CRYPTO.decrypt(data['password'].encode()).decode(), data['last update']))
            if len(data_file) != 0:
                indicator.config(text=f"{round(rows[0]/ROWS_PER_PAGE)+1} / {math.ceil(len(data_file)/ROWS_PER_PAGE)}")

    def update_table():
        data_table.delete(*data_table.get_children())
        for n, data in enumerate(data_file.iloc[rows[0]:rows[1]].iterrows()):
            data = data[1]
            data_table.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=n,
                              values=(data['website'], data['username'], CRYPTO.decrypt(data['password'].encode()).decode(), data['last update']))

    def update_delete():
        if data_table.focus() != '':
            global data_file
            data_file.index = [x for x in range(0, len(data_file))]
            if len(data_table.get_children()) != 0:
                index = data_table.focus()
                next_index = list(data_table.get_children()).index(index)
                data_file = data_file.drop(axis=0, labels=(int(index))+rows[0])

                data_table.delete(index)
                update_table()

                if next_index != 0:
                    data_table.focus(data_table.get_children()[next_index-1])
                    data_table.selection_set(data_table.get_children()[next_index-1])
                elif len(data_table.get_children()) != 0:
                    data_table.focus(data_table.get_children()[next_index])
                    data_table.selection_set(data_table.get_children()[next_index])

                #data_file.to_csv(path_or_buf=f"{RESOURCE_PATH}/passwordmanager.csv", mode="w", header=True, index=False)

                if math.ceil(len(data_file) / ROWS_PER_PAGE) == len(data_file) / ROWS_PER_PAGE and len(data_file) != 0:
                    indicator.config(text=f"{round(rows[0] / ROWS_PER_PAGE) + 1} / {math.ceil(len(data_file) / ROWS_PER_PAGE)}")

    def search():
        searched_item = askstring('Search','Website name:')
        if searched_item is not None:
            if searched_item in data_file['website'].tolist():
                data = data_file[data_file['website'] == searched_item].to_dict('list')
                showinfo('Details',f'Website: {str(*data["website"])}\n'
                                   f'Username: {str(*data["username"])}\n'
                                   f'Password: {CRYPTO.decrypt(str(*data["password"]).encode()).decode()}\n')
            else:
                showerror('Error','Website not found!')

    def edit_cell(event):
        def destroy_popups():
            for child in data_table.winfo_children():
                if type(child) == Entry:
                    child.destroy()

        def save_data(event):
            data_col = data_file.columns[int(cell_col[1])-1]
            data_file[data_col][int(cell_row)] = edit_box.get()
            #data_file.to_csv(path_or_buf=f"{RESOURCE_PATH}/passwordmanager.csv", mode="w", header=True, index=False)
            update_table()
            edit_box.destroy()

        destroy_popups()
        cell_row = data_table.identify_row(event.y)
        cell_col = data_table.identify_column(event.x)
        if data_table.focus() != '' and cell_row != '':
            x, y, width, height = data_table.bbox(cell_row,cell_col)
            edit_box = Entry(data_table,width=int(width/7),justify=CENTER)
            edit_box.insert(0,string=data_table.item(cell_row)['values'][int(cell_col[1])-1])
            edit_box.place(x=x+(int(width/15)), y=y)
            edit_box.focus()
            edit_box.bind('<Return>',lambda event: save_data(event))


    clear_frame(window)

    headline = Label(text="Password Manager", font=("Ariel", 20, "bold"), fg=MAIN_COLOR)
    headline.place(x=200, y=10)

    small_logo = Canvas(width=46, height=46, highlightthickness=0)
    small_logo.create_image(23, 23, image=SMALL_LOGO)
    small_logo.place(y=5, x=450)

    search_button = Button(image=SEARCH_LOGO,borderwidth=0,command=search)
    search_button.place(x=600,y=7)
    trash_button = Button(image=TRASH_LOGO, borderwidth=0,highlightcolor=MAIN_COLOR, fg=MAIN_COLOR, command=update_delete)
    trash_button.place(x=650, y=7)

    style = Style(window)
    style.theme_use("clam")
    style.configure("Treeview", background=MAIN_WHITE,
                    fieldbackground=MAIN_WHITE, foreground="black")

    data_table = Treeview(window, height=24)
    data_table['columns'] = tuple(data_file.keys())
    data_table.column("#0", width=0, stretch=NO)
    data_table.bind("<Double-1>",lambda event: edit_cell(event))

    rows = [0, ROWS_PER_PAGE]

    if len(data_file) < 2:
        rows[1] = len(data_file)

    for col in data_table['columns']:
        data_table.heading(col, text=col, anchor=CENTER)
        if col != 'password':
            data_table.column(col, width=0, anchor=CENTER)
        else:
            data_table.column('password', width=50, anchor=CENTER)

    for n, data in enumerate(data_file.iloc[rows[0]:rows[1]].iterrows()):
        data = data[1]
        data_table.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=n, values=(data['website'], data['username'], CRYPTO.decrypt(data['password'].encode()).decode(), data['last update']))

    data_table.pack(fill="x", pady=50)

    last_page_button = Button(borderwidth=0, text="last page", fg=MAIN_COLOR, bg=MAIN_WHITE, command=lambda: last_page(rows))
    last_page_button.place(x=200, y=465)

    if len(data_file) == 0:
        indicator = Label(text=f"{round(rows[0]/ROWS_PER_PAGE)+1} / {math.ceil(len(data_file)/ROWS_PER_PAGE)+1}", fg=MAIN_COLOR)
    else:
        indicator = Label(
            text=f"{round(rows[0] / ROWS_PER_PAGE) + 1} / {math.ceil(len(data_file) / ROWS_PER_PAGE)}",
            fg=MAIN_COLOR)
    indicator.place(x=340, y=467)

    next_page_button = Button(borderwidth=0, text="next page", fg=MAIN_COLOR, bg=MAIN_WHITE, command=lambda: next_page(rows))
    next_page_button.place(x=450, y=465)

    return_button = Button(image=RETURN_IMAGE, borderwidth=0, command=main_page)
    return_button.place(x=10, y=5)

    window.mainloop()


def main_page():
    clear_frame(window)

    small_logo = Canvas(width=200, height=189, highlightthickness=0)
    small_logo.create_image(100, 100, image=LOGO_IMAGE)
    small_logo.pack(pady=40)

    display_button = Button(text="Display", bg=MAIN_COLOR, fg=MAIN_WHITE, activebackground=MAIN_WHITE,
                            activeforeground=MAIN_COLOR, borderwidth=0, command=display_page)
    display_button.pack()

    add_button = Button(text="Add", bg=MAIN_COLOR, fg=MAIN_WHITE, activebackground=MAIN_WHITE,
                           activeforeground=MAIN_COLOR, borderwidth=0, command=add_page)
    add_button.pack(pady=60)

    change_password_button = Button(text='Change Password',bg=MAIN_COLOR,fg=MAIN_WHITE,activebackground=MAIN_WHITE,
                                    activeforeground=MAIN_COLOR,borderwidth=0,command=change_password)
    change_password_button.pack()

    if PASSWORD == None:
        admin_verify()

    window.mainloop()


window = Tk()
window.geometry("700x500")
# window.bind("<Key>", motion)

RESOURCE_PATH = "resources/PasswordManager"
LOGO_IMAGE = PhotoImage(file=f"{RESOURCE_PATH}/logo.png")
SMALL_LOGO = PhotoImage(file=f"{RESOURCE_PATH}/small_logo.png")
RETURN_IMAGE = PhotoImage(file=f"{RESOURCE_PATH}/return.png")
TRASH_LOGO = PhotoImage(file=f"{RESOURCE_PATH}/trash.png")
SEARCH_LOGO = PhotoImage(file=f"{RESOURCE_PATH}/search.png")
MAIN_COLOR = "#D4483B"
MAIN_WHITE = "#F0F0F0"
ROWS_PER_PAGE = 18
PASSWORD = None
CRYPTO = Fernet(b'YnhYyxH_YkYZvOYm9L04CJibItOd4BFEZLn1JCnRWWA=')
data_file = None

main_page()
```

I am in a learning process and the program may not be secure enough to publish as a real-life program, as this program focused on the code and GUI training and less about the real use of it for your own passwords.

I am not an artist and never edited pictures so much before but I had to create some of my own resources that I couldn't find online so please forgive any lack of artistic resources.

Comment: I cloned your GitHub and tried to run your code. It is erroring out because of missing `search.png`. Can you check if you have committed the right files?

Comment: you are correct , added that missing file

Answer (score 2):

Avoid `from tkinter import *` - it fills your namespace with a lot of symbols that you don't actually care about (nor do any secondary importers of your module).

`class Tk(Tk):` is pretty disastrous - you should never name a child class the same as its parent class, especially if it's a well-known class like `Tk`.

`f'{RESOURCE_PATH}/data_file.enc'` can be made portable by use of `pathlib.Path`; something like

```py
RESOURCE_PATH = Path("resources/PasswordManager")
# ...
with (RESOURCE_PATH / 'data_file.enc').open(mode='wb') as save_file:
```

Your `Tk.destroy()` has surprising side-effects - it saves a file whose handle is in the global namespace. It shouldn't do that - instead, your GUI class and business logic should be separate, you shouldn't have any global variables (other than those for constants), and the closure of your GUI should delegate file operations to your business logic in a separate class.

Add type hints to your function signatures, for instance `def change_password() -> bool`.

In `generate_password`, your `chars` has a handful of issues. If you keep it as-is, then instead of writing out the whole latin alphabet you should make use of the [constants in the `string` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html). However, that leads to use of characters that are visually ambiguous and difficult to distinguish, like lowercase L, uppercase O, etc. Consider removing these visually ambiguous characters, or (better) replacing the password with a [passphrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passphrase#Compared_to_passwords) which is easier to remember, and depending on context may be more secure.

[Read the documentation, and never use `random` for cryptography](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

> **Warning:** The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be used for security purposes. For security or cryptographic uses, see the `secrets` module.

Don't overwrite variables with values of a different type, as you do in `data = data[1]`. Use a new variable name.

`lambda event: save_data(event)` can be replaced with a simple function reference `save_data`.

Replace `PASSWORD == None` with `PASSWORD is None` due to `None` being a singleton.

From `window = Tk()` onward, move all of that code into a `main` function called by an import guard:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Lots more to improve, but that's a first pass. Especially, the separation of your GUI and business logic and removal of global state will go a long way.

Comment: thanskf or the reply i noted myself all of your points, feel free to check my second project since that one again i wrote this sone after 14days of learning 
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288710/python-beginner-gui

Comment: just one thing i have to say about this section:
class Tk(Tk): is pretty disastrous - you should never name a child class the same as its parent class, especially if it's a well-known class like Tk.
i called the class Tk to overwrite the main Tk.destroy function so it will save the file even if somoen clicked X on the program and not each time the user edit password
as you said in your notes maybe i should have use this method to save the files but it was intentionally overwrite

Comment: Don't do that. It's trivially easy to write a class with a different name.

Comment: so the better way to do it is to write a window class that inherits Tk with new function name?

Comment: The better way is to not inherit at all, and instantiate `Tk` as a class member; but short of that - just make a class with a new class name (not function name)