# Python - beginner - GUI

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been learning python for 1.5 month now I am learning in my free time between job and other life commitments so my progress may be slow. It may take time for me to reply but I am interested in opinions and reviews on my code in order to get better faster and identify any mistakes I have made.

I would appreciate ideas to improve the code or any thoughts you may have. I would also appreciate reviews focusing on:

- code readability
- code efficiency

Learning language program with few different subjects and languages included.

I have taken all my data from the internet, with translations through Google Translate so the data may be inaccurate. I am also not an artist, please excuse the graphics I've created.

Buttons.py

```
from tkinter import Button

class Button(Button):
    def __init__(self,master, command=None):
        super().__init__(master=master)
        self['borderwidth'] = 0
        self['bg'] = self.master['bg']
        self['command'] = command
        self['activebackground'] = self.master['bg']

class LanguageSettingsButton(Button):
    def __init__(self,master, image, command):
        super().__init__(master=master,command=command)
        self['image'] = image

class MenuButton(Button):
    def __init__(self,master, text, command,font):
        super().__init__(master=master,command=command)
        self['text'] = text
        self['font'] = (font,25)
        self['fg'] = '#040814'
```

Data.py

```
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

class Data():
    def __del__(self):
        json.data = {
            'native_lang' : self.native_lang,
            'active_language' : self.active_language
        }
        self.prase_data['native_lang'] = self.native_lang
        self.prase_data[f'active_language_{self.native_lang}'] = self.active_language
        self.settings_file.write(json.dumps(self.prase_data,indent=4))

    def __init__(self):
        self.supported_languages = ['en','fr','de','es','ja','it','he']
        self.subjects = ['Top 100','Top 400','Top 1000','Animals','Food']

        self.font = 'David'
        self.font_2 = 'FuturistStencil'
        self.colors = {
            'main' : '#b469ff',
            'white' : '#FAF9F6'
        }

        self.word_list = None
        self.progress_list = None

        self.logos = {}
        self.dictionary = {}
        self.borders = {}
        self.generals = {}

        self.settings_file = open('resources/pylang/settings.json',mode='r')
        self.prase_data = json.load(self.settings_file)
        self.native_lang = self.prase_data['native_lang']
        self.active_language = self.prase_data[f'active_language_{self.native_lang}']
        self.settings_file = open('resources/pylang/settings.json', mode='w')

        self.load_images()
    def load_images(self):
        for lang in self.supported_languages:
            self.logos[lang] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=f'resources/pylang/images/{lang}.png')
        self.logos['main'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fp='resources/pylang/images/main_logo.png'))
        self.logos['main_small'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fp='resources/pylang/images/main_logo.png').resize(size=(140,35)))


        self.borders['border'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='resources/pylang/images/border.png')
        self.borders['big_up'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='resources/pylang/images/big_border_upside.png')
        self.borders['big_down'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='resources/pylang/images/big_border_downside.png')
        self.borders['selected'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='resources/pylang/images/selected_border.png')
        self.borders['non'] =ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='resources/pylang/images/non_selected_border.png')
        self.borders['shade'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='resources/pylang/images/border_shade.png')
        self.borders['loadbar'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='resources/pylang/images/loadbar_border.png')

        self.generals['return'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='resources/pylang/images/return.png')
        self.generals['start'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fp='resources/pylang/images/start.png').resize(size=(60,60)))
        self.generals['start_s'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fp='resources/pylang/images/start.png').resize(size=(49,40)))
        self.generals['loadbar'] = Image.open(fp='resources/pylang/images/loadbar.png')
        self.generals['check_button'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='resources/pylang/images/check_button.png')
        self.generals['cancel_button'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='resources/pylang/images/cancel_button.png')

    def load_menu(self,lang):
        temp_csv = pd.read_csv('resources/pylang/menu.csv')
        return temp_csv[lang]

    def load_language(self,lang):
        temp_csv = pd.read_csv('resources/pylang/languages.csv')
        return temp_csv[lang]

    def get_loadbar(self,percentage):
        temp_loadbar = self.generals['loadbar'].crop((0,0,155*(percentage/100),15))
        temp_loadbar = ImageTk.PhotoImage(temp_loadbar)
        return temp_loadbar

    def get_lists(self,subject,lang):
        self.word_list = pd.read_csv(f'resources/pylang/words/{subject}.csv').copy()
        self.progress_list = pd.read_csv(f'resources/pylang/progress/{subject}_{self.native_lang}_progress.csv').copy()

        for n,word in enumerate(self.progress_list[lang]):
            self.word_list[self.word_list[lang] == word] = np.nan

    def update_progress(self,subject,learned_lang,word):
        word_list = self.progress_list[learned_lang].dropna()

        self.progress_list.loc[len(word_list),learned_lang] = word
        self.progress_list.to_csv(path_or_buf=f'resources/pylang/progress/{subject}_{self.native_lang}_progress.csv',index=False)

        self.word_list[self.word_list[learned_lang] == word] = np.nan
```

SubFrame.py

```
from tkinter import Frame,Canvas,Label
from Buttons import *

class SubFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master,data,headline):
        super().__init__(master=master,width=master.width,height=master.height,bg=master['bg'])
        self.width = master.width
        self.height = master.height
        self.pack_propagate(False)
        self.pack()

        self.data = data

        self.header_frame = Frame(master=self,width=self.width,height=self.height*0.08,
                                  bg=self.data.colors['white'])
        self.header_frame.pack_propagate(False)
        self.header_frame.pack()

        self.return_button = LanguageSettingsButton(master=self.header_frame, image=self.data.generals['return'],
                                                    command=self.destroy)
        self.return_button.pack(side='left', pady=5, padx=10)

        self.logo = Canvas(master=self.header_frame, width=140, height=35, highlightthickness=0,
                           bg=self.header_frame['bg'])
        self.logo.create_image(70, 35 / 2, image=self.data.logos['main_small'])
        self.logo.pack(side='right', pady=5, padx=10)

        self.header = Label(master=self.header_frame, text=headline, font=(self.data.font, 20),
                            bg=self.header_frame['bg'])
        self.header.pack(pady=5)

        self.main_frame = Frame(master=self, width=self.width, height=self.height - 50, bg=self['bg'])
        self.main_frame.pack()

    def clear_frames(self):
        self.main_frame.destroy()
        self.header_frame.destroy()
```

mainwindow.py

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import Tk,Frame,Canvas
from Data import Data
from Buttons import LanguageSettingsButton,MenuButton
from NewLearnFrame import NewLearnFrame
from ContinueLearnFrame import ContinueLearnFrame

MAIN_COLOR = '#b469ff'
MAIN_COLOR_LIGHT = '#cd9cff'
SECOND_COLOR = '#040814'
SECOND_COLOR_LIGHT = '#0c193e'
OFF_WHITE = '#FAF9F6'

class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self, title, width, height):
        #window settings
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)
        self.geometry('1x1+600+200')
        self.minsize(width=width, height=height)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self['bg'] = MAIN_COLOR

        #general settings
        self.data = Data()

        #settings_frame
        self.settings_container = Frame(master=self,bg=self['bg'],borderwidth=0)
        self.settings_container.place(x=self.width*0.94, y=self.height*0.01)

        self.language_button = LanguageSettingsButton(master=self.settings_container,
                                                      image=self.data.logos[self.data.native_lang],
                                                      command=self.open_lang_menu)
        self.language_button.grid(column=0,row=0)


        #menu_frame
        self.menu = self.data.load_menu(self.data.native_lang)
        item_spaces = 25

        self.menu_container = Frame(master=self,bg=OFF_WHITE)
        self.menu_container.place(x=self.width/2, y=self.height/2,anchor='center')

        self.logo = Canvas(self.menu_container,width=240,height=60,highlightthickness=0,bg=self.menu_container['bg'])
        self.logo.create_image(0,0,image = self.data.logos['main'],anchor='nw')
        self.logo.pack(pady=item_spaces/2,anchor='center')

        self.learn_new_button = MenuButton(self.menu_container,text=self.menu[0],font=self.data.font,
                                           command=lambda : NewLearnFrame(self,self.data))
        self.learn_new_button.pack(pady=item_spaces)

        self.continue_learn_button = MenuButton(self.menu_container, text=self.menu[1],font=self.data.font,
                                                command=lambda: ContinueLearnFrame(master=self,data=self.data))
        self.continue_learn_button.pack(pady=item_spaces)

        self.exit_button = MenuButton(self.menu_container,font=self.data.font,text=self.menu[2],command=self.destroy)
        self.exit_button.pack(pady=item_spaces)


    def open_lang_menu(self):
        if len(self.settings_container.children) <= 1:
            row_parm = 0
            for language in self.data.supported_languages:
                if language != self.data.native_lang:
                    row_parm += 1
                    LanguageSettingsButton(master=self.settings_container, image=self.data.logos[language],
                                           command=lambda lang=language: self.update_language(lang)).grid(column=0,row=row_parm)
        else:
            self.close_lang_menu()

    def update_language(self,lang):
        self.data.native_lang = lang
        self.language_button.config(image=self.data.logos[lang])
        self.menu = self.data.load_menu(self.data.native_lang)
        self.learn_new_button['text'] = self.menu[0]
        self.continue_learn_button['text'] = self.menu[1]
        self.exit_button['text'] = self.menu[2]
        self.close_lang_menu()
        self.data.active_language = self.data.prase_data[f'active_language_{self.data.native_lang}']

        for subject in self.data.subjects:
            try:
                open(f'resources/pylang/progress/{subject}_{self.data.native_lang}_progress.csv')
            except:
                df = pd.DataFrame(columns=self.data.supported_languages)
                df.to_csv(f'resources/pylang/progress/{subject}_{self.data.native_lang}_progress.csv')

    def close_lang_menu(self):
        for child in self.settings_container.winfo_children()[1:]:
            child.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    MainWindow = MainWindow('Pylang',800,600)

    MainWindow.mainloop()
```

NewLearnFrame.py

```
from tkinter import Canvas
from Buttons import LanguageSettingsButton
from SubFrame import SubFrame

class NewLearnFrame(SubFrame):
    def __init__(self,master,data):
        super().__init__(master=master, data=data, headline='Choose Language')

        self.lang_cards = []
        self.selected_card = None
        self.language_list = self.data.load_language(self.data.native_lang)

        self.main_frame.grid_propagate(False)
        for x in range(0,int(len(self.data.supported_languages)/3)+1):
            if x < 3:
                self.main_frame.columnconfigure(index=x,pad=25)
            self.main_frame.rowconfigure(index=x,pad=25)

        row = 0
        col = 0
        for index,lang in enumerate(self.data.supported_languages):
            card = Canvas(master=self.main_frame, width=240, height=160,bg=self.main_frame['bg'],highlightthickness=0)
            card.create_image(120, 80, image=self.data.borders['non'],tag='border')
            card.create_text(120,30,text=self.language_list[index],font=(self.data.font,25))
            card.create_image(120, 80, image=self.data.logos[lang])
            if lang == self.data.native_lang or lang in self.data.active_language:
                card.create_image(120,80,image=self.data.borders['shade'],tag='shade')

            card.grid(column=col,row=row)
            card.bind("<Button-1>",lambda e,i=index:self.select_card(i))
            col += 1
            if col == 3:
                col = 0
                row += 1
            self.lang_cards.append(card)

        self.start_learn_button = LanguageSettingsButton(master=self.main_frame,image=self.data.generals['start'],
                                                         command=lambda : self.add_language(self.selected_card))
        self.start_learn_button.grid(column=2,row=row,sticky='se',pady=10)

    def add_language(self,language):
        self.data.active_language.append(self.data.supported_languages[self.lang_cards.index(language)])
        self.destroy()

    def select_card(self,index):
        if self.data.native_lang != self.data.supported_languages[index] and self.data.supported_languages[index] not in self.data.active_language:
            if self.selected_card == None:

                self.selected_card = self.lang_cards[index]
                self.selected_card.itemconfig('border',image=self.data.borders['selected'])
                return

            self.selected_card.itemconfig('border',image=self.data.borders['non'])
            self.selected_card = self.lang_cards[index]
            self.selected_card.itemconfig('border', image=self.data.borders['selected'])
```

ContinueLearnFrame.py

```
import random
import numpy as np
from SubFrame import SubFrame
from Buttons import LanguageSettingsButton
from tkinter import Canvas

class ContinueLearnFrame(SubFrame):
    def __init__(self,master,data,selected_lang=None):
        super().__init__(master=master, data=data, headline='Choose Language')

        self.main_frame.grid_propagate(False)
        self.main_frame.pack_propagate(False)

        self.cards = []
        self.cards_loadbar = []
        self.buttons = []
        self.words = {}
        self.selected_lang = selected_lang

        if self.selected_lang == None:
            self.load_languages()

    def learn_language(self,lang):
        self.selected_lang = lang
        self.load_subjects()

    def erase(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            card.destroy()
        for button in self.buttons:
            button.destroy()

        self.cards = []
        self.buttons = []
        self.cards_loadbar = []

    def load_languages(self):
        self.erase()

        self.header.config(text="Choose Language")
        self.return_button.config(command=self.destroy)

        for col in range(0, 3):
            self.main_frame.columnconfigure(index=col, pad=25)
        for row in range(0, int(len(self.data.active_language) / 3) + 1):
            self.main_frame.rowconfigure(index=row, pad=25)

        col = 0
        row = 0
        for index, lang in enumerate(self.data.active_language):
            card = Canvas(master=self.main_frame, width=240, height=160, bg=self.main_frame['bg'], highlightthickness=0)
            card.create_image(120, 80, image=self.data.borders['border'], tag='border')
            card.create_text(120, 50, text=self.data.active_language[index], font=(self.data.font, 25))
            card.create_image(120, 110, image=self.data.logos[lang])
            card.grid(column=col, row=row)
            card.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, l=lang: self.learn_language(l))
            if col < 2:
                col += 1
            else:
                row += 1
                col = 0
            self.cards.append(card)

    def load_subjects(self):

        self.erase()

        self.header.config(text="Choose Subject")
        self.return_button.config(command=self.load_languages)


        for col in range(0, 3):
            self.main_frame.columnconfigure(index=col, pad=25)
        for row in range(0, int(len(self.data.subjects) / 3) + 1):
            self.main_frame.rowconfigure(index=row, pad=25)
        col = 0
        row = 0
        for index, subj in enumerate(self.data.subjects):
            self.data.get_lists(subject=subj,lang=self.selected_lang)

            total = len(self.data.word_list[self.selected_lang])
            progress = len(self.data.progress_list[self.selected_lang].dropna())
            precent = round((progress/total)*100)

            self.cards_loadbar.append(self.data.get_loadbar(precent))
            card = Canvas(master=self.main_frame, width=240, height=160, bg=self.main_frame['bg'], highlightthickness=0)
            if len(self.data.word_list[self.selected_lang].dropna()) != 0:
                card.create_image(120, 80, image=self.data.borders['loadbar'], tag='border')
                card.create_image(14, 135, image=self.cards_loadbar[-1], tag='loadbar',anchor='w')
                card.create_text(205, 135, text=f'{precent}%', font=(self.data.font, 16))
                card.create_text(120, 90, text=f'{progress}/'
                                               f'{total}',
                                 font=(self.data.font, 25))
                card.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, sub=self.data.subjects[index]: self.load_learn_program(sub))
            else:
                card.create_image(120, 80, image=self.data.borders['border'], tag='border')
                card.create_text(120, 135, text=f'COMPLETED', font=(self.data.font, 16))
                card.create_text(120, 90, text='100%',
                                 font=(self.data.font, 25))

            card.create_text(120, 40, text=self.data.subjects[index], font=(self.data.font, 30))

            card.grid(column=col, row=row)

            if col < 2:
                col += 1
            else:
                row += 1
                col = 0
            self.cards.append(card)

    def load_learn_program(self,subject):
        self.data.get_lists(subject=subject,lang=self.selected_lang)

        def load_cards(self):
            card_upside = Canvas(master=self.main_frame, width=600, height=400, bg=self.main_frame['bg'],
                                 highlightthickness=0)
            card_upside.create_image(300, 200, image=self.data.borders['big_up'], tag='border')
            card_upside.create_text(300, 100,
                                    text=f'{self.data.load_language(lang=self.data.native_lang)[self.data.supported_languages.index(self.selected_lang)]}',
                                    font=(self.data.font, 50),
                                    tags='headline')
            card_upside.create_text(300,250,text='',font=(self.data.font, 30),tags='word')
            card_upside.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: swap_cards(self, 0))
            card_upside.pack(pady=40)
            self.cards.append(card_upside)


            card_downside = Canvas(master=self.main_frame, width=600, height=400, bg=self.main_frame['bg'],
                                   highlightthickness=0)
            card_downside.create_image(300, 200, image=self.data.borders['big_down'], tag='border')
            card_downside.create_text(300, 100,
                                    text=f'{self.data.load_language(lang=self.data.native_lang)[self.data.supported_languages.index(self.data.native_lang)]}',
                                    font=(self.data.font, 50),
                                    tags='headline')
            card_downside.create_text(300,250,text='',font=(self.data.font, 30),tags='word')
            card_downside.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: swap_cards(self, 1))
            self.cards.append(card_downside)

        def swap_cards(self, index):
            if index == 0:
                self.cards[0].pack_forget()
                self.cards[1].pack(pady=40)
            else:
                self.cards[0].pack(pady=40)
                self.cards[1].pack_forget()

        def update_cards(self):
            while(True):
                try:
                    random_word = random.choice(self.data.word_list[self.selected_lang].dropna().tolist())
                    if random_word != np.nan and random_word != np.NaN:
                        current_word_index = self.data.word_list.index[self.data.word_list[self.selected_lang] == random_word].tolist()[0]
                        self.words['native'] = self.data.word_list[self.data.native_lang][current_word_index]
                        self.words['learned'] = self.data.word_list[self.selected_lang][current_word_index]
                        self.cards[0].itemconfigure('word', text=f'{self.words['learned']}')
                        self.cards[1].itemconfigure('word', text=f'{self.words['native']}')
                        break
                except IndexError as e:
                    self.cards[0].itemconfigure(tagOrId='headline',text='Congratulations')
                    self.cards[0].itemconfigure(tagOrId='word',text='Subject completed')
                    for button in self.buttons:
                        button.destroy()
                    break

            try:
                self.cards[0].pack_info()
            except:
                swap_cards(self,1)

        def approval_word(self):
            self.data.update_progress(subject=subject,learned_lang=self.selected_lang,word=self.words['learned'])
            update_cards(self)

        self.erase()

        self.header.config(text=f"{subject}")
        self.return_button.config(command=self.load_subjects)


        load_cards(self)
        update_cards(self)


        check_button = LanguageSettingsButton(master=self.main_frame, image=self.data.generals['check_button'],
                                               command=lambda : approval_word(self))
        check_button.place(x=300, y=500, anchor='center')
        self.buttons.append(check_button)

        cancel_button = LanguageSettingsButton(master=self.main_frame, image=self.data.generals['cancel_button'],
                                               command=lambda : update_cards(self))
        cancel_button.place(x=500,y=500,anchor='center')
        self.buttons.append(cancel_button)
```

- [full code - Github](https://github.com/SeanR11/Pylang)

Answer (score 3):

## The good stuff

- The interface and the data model are not intricated: the data model is not dependent on *Tkinter* at all
- Use of `if __name__ == "__main__":` clause
- The size of the methods and classes is OK in most cases
- The naming is globally OK

## Style

Make sure to take a look at [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) to properly format your code. There are inconsistencies in:

- The spacing between the classes/functions (two newlines expected) and methods (one newline expected)
- The spacing after the commas (one space expected)
- The spacing in comments (two spaces before `#`, one after)
- ...

If you want to properly format your code without having to worry, you could use a tool like [black](https://pypi.org/project/black/) to do that for you.

Your files should be named with the *snake_case* convention: `buttons.py`, `data.py`, `new_learn_frame.py`...

## About type annotations

As a beginner in python, this should not be your first priority, but you need to know that [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) exist, and that they can help you.

Main advantages:

- Autocompletion: when using a proper code editor or IDE, type annotations help a lot for an accurate autocompletion.
- Documentation: when reading code of other people, or code that you wrote a while ago, they help to understand what classes/functions/methods expect as inputs, and what they return.
- Code correctness: type hints help detect errors statically, in your IDE or code editor, or in external tools like *mypy*.

## Inner functions

Using inner functions (`load_cards`, `update_cards`...) that take a `self` argument is quite surprising in `ContinueLearnFrame.py`. These functions could be replaced by simple methods:

```py
class ContinueLearnFrame(SubFrame):
    ...

    def _swap_cards(self, index: int) -> None:
        ...

    def _load_cards(self) -> None:
        ...
        card_upside.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self._swap_cards(0))
        ...
        card_downside.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self._swap_cards(1))
    
    def _update_cards(self) -> None:
        ...
        except:
            self._swap_cards(1)

    def _approval_word(self, subject: str) -> None:
        ...
        self._update_cards()

    def load_learn_program(self, subject: str) -> None:
        ...
        self._load_cards()
        self._update_cards()
        check_button = LanguageSettingsButton(
            master=self.main_frame,
            image=self.data.generals["check_button"],
            command=lambda: self._approval_word(subject),
        )
        ...
        cancel_button = LanguageSettingsButton(
            master=self.main_frame,
            image=self.data.generals["cancel_button"],
            command=self._update_cards,
        )
```

The `_` in front of the method names is just a standard way (enforced by [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)) to indicate that the method is private, and should not be accessed outside the class.

## Equality test with `None`

```py
if self.selected_lang == None:
    ...
```

`None` is a singleton, and this test should be replaced with:

```py
if self.selected_lang is None:
    ...
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14247383/17674349) for more information.

## Overwriting names

There are some spots where variables are unintentionally overwritten, and that could lead to bugs.

### MainWindow

```py
MainWindow = MainWindow('Pylang',800,600)
```

Here you are overwriting the `MainWindow` class, and it is not possible to create another independent `MainWindow` anymore. Also, the variable that stores the instantiated `MainWindow` should follow the *snake_case* naming convention:

```py
main_window = MainWindow("Pylang", 800, 600)
main_window.mainloop()
```

### Button

```py
from tkinter import Button

class Button(Button):
    ...
```

Here, the `tkinter.Button` class of `tkinter` is also overwritten, which makes it impossible to use it in the following parts of the module. You should consider doing:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class Button(tk.Button):
    ...
```

## Unused code

Some variables/methods are never used:

- `Data.font_2`
- `Data.dictionary`
- `SubFrame.clear_frames()`

They clutter the code and can slow down the execution (probably not here though).
They can be detected with specialized tools like *vulture*, or more generic linters like *pylint* or *flake8*.

## About lambdas

Variable that are not used intentionally should be prefixed with `_` and there is no need to over-complicate things here (`ContinueLearnFrame.py`):

```py
card.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, l=lang: self.learn_language(l))
```

could be written:

```py
card.bind("<Button-1>", lambda _e: self.learn_language(lang))
```

## Use well-defined data structures instead of dicts

In the `Data` class, some attributes would deserve a proper data structure, for example `logos`, `borders`, `generals`... Using simple dictionaries in this case is error prone,
as it is easy to mistype a key when accessing the elements.

By declaring a `dataclass`, you get access to autocompletion, and other tools can help you
detect errors in your code without having to execute anything (*mypy*).

The `generals` attribute would look like:

```py
...
from dataclasses import dataclass
...

@dataclass
class GenericImages:
    return_img: ImageTk.PhotoImage
    start: ImageTk.PhotoImage
    start_s: ImageTk.PhotoImage
    loadbar: Image.Image
    check_button: ImageTk.PhotoImage
    cancel_button: ImageTk.PhotoImage


class Data:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        ...
        self.generals: GenericImages | None = None
        ...

    def load_images(self) -> None:
        ...
        self.generals = GenericImages(
            return_img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="resources/pylang/images/return.png"),
            start=ImageTk.PhotoImage(
                Image.open(fp="resources/pylang/images/start.png").resize(size=(60, 60))
            ),
            start_s=ImageTk.PhotoImage(
                Image.open(fp="resources/pylang/images/start.png").resize(size=(49, 40))
            ),
            loadbar=Image.open(fp="resources/pylang/images/loadbar.png"),
            check_button=ImageTk.PhotoImage(
                file="resources/pylang/images/check_button.png"
            ),
            cancel_button=ImageTk.PhotoImage(
                file="resources/pylang/images/cancel_button.png"
            ),
        )
```

Accessing the attributes is done like one would do with a standard class:

```py
self.generals.check_button
```

## Catching broad exception

In the `MainWindow` there is a confusing piece of code:

```py
try:
    open(f'resources/pylang/progress/{subject}_{self.data.native_lang}_progress.csv')
except:
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=self.data.supported_languages)
    df.to_csv(f'resources/pylang/progress/{subject}_{self.data.native_lang}_progress.csv')
```

Here:

- The `except` clause is too broad: this can hide bugs, and it makes your intentions unclear
- Using `open` should lead to a call to `close` at some point (or a `with` statement should be used)
- The generation of the path string is duplicated

What you probably want to do is:

```py
progress_csv_path = 'resources/pylang/progress/{subject}_{self.data.native_lang}_progress.csv'
if not os.path.exists(progress_csv_path):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=self.data.supported_languages)
    df.to_csv(progress_csv_path)
```

## Conclusion

There is a lot to say (and I'm sure I would have more to say if I dug deeper), but for a progress of a month and a half, it's pretty good. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Wow, first of all, thanks for the review.

I really appreciate it.
I have taken all the notes. I will publish my next project soon, and I will include all these notes.

I would like it if you could have some time and review my next project as well, so I will have more factors to improve on.

Comment: I posted my new project. If you have any free time, I would like you to review my code, as I got good points from you last time. I have used all of your tips except data structures, as I can see why knowing this idea might help in big projects or collaborative projects to prevent typing errors and get achieve completion. But is it really necessary to define a data structure in small projects? If so, let me know, so I can implement data structures in my next projects.

Comment: I would say that the point on the data structure is the most important of my post. It is a really good habit to define the data your application depends on. Those data structures can define internal concepts: the state of your application, objects that are closely related to each other that must be transferred between modules (like your images), etc... Keeping a definition at a single location helps a lot when it comes to centralizing the core concepts of a project, writing documentation, etc... Defining them early is important, as your IDE cannot help you when everything is dynamic.